# How to achieve bindingnavigatoer control functionality in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am migrating application from winforms to WPF.

In winforms I had bindingnavigator which we can use to navigate in dataset.

I know how can we do it in winforms.

[image]

How can we achieve the same functionality in WPF (I am very much new to WPF ) as well ?

Comment: There's no such thing in WPF, because it's really not needed, nor wanted really. Why do you need that thing?

Comment: @HighCore I have to implement exact same UI as before. If it is not needed then can guide how it can be achieved ?

Comment: That makes no sense at all. WPF supports much better user experiences than winforms. There's no point in replicating the limited functionality of winforms in a much powerful platform. Yet, if you want to do that, just do it with an `ItemsControl`, a couple of `DelegateCommand`s for the buttons, and a `ContentPresenter` to show the active record.

Comment: it will be nice of you if you can give link to some tutorials for this as I am very much new to WPF

Comment: @vaibhav : look at the links below, it may be useful.

Comment: @vaibhav : if you can accept this as answer, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please have look at Christian Nagel's blog. It has two articles regarding same. There is no such control in WPF but in these articles, you can find a way to implement it.

> > [Part - 1](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2010/08/bindingnavigator-for-wpf-part-1---creating.html)
> >     [Part - 2](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2010/08/bindingnavigator-for-wpf-part-2using.html)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged in SO. Please post the relevant bits here in case the article is deleted or otherwise becomes inaccessible.

Comment: @HighCore : It is not possible each time to put detailed answer in case of new concept or implementation. So this is the only way we can provide the   answer. It is not good to downvote answers.

Comment: `It is not possible each time to put detailed answer` - yes it is. RT*M, link only answers are discouraged in SO.